# Typescript compile error when using AWS SDK

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, tsc

### Problem

I'm using `Typescript` with [@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper-annotations](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js), and it works but keeps throwing compile errors. These errors occurred on both `macOS` and `Ubuntu 16.04` :

```
../../node_modules/@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper/build/protocols.d.ts(31,45): error TS1005: '=' expected.

31 export declare const DynamoDbSchema: unique symbol;
                                               ~~~~~~



../../node_modules/@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper/build/protocols.d.ts(52,44): error TS1005: '=' expected.

52 export declare const DynamoDbTable: unique symbol;
                                              ~~~~~~


../../node_modules/@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper/build/protocols.d.ts(81,50): error TS1005: '=' expected.

81 export declare const DynamoDbDirtyFields: unique symbol;
                                                    ~~~~~~
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? I appreciate your help. :)

### Settings

I've added `node_modules` as excluded folder in `tsconfig.json`, and here are my settings:

- tsc: 2.8.1
- npm: 5.3.0
- aws-sdk: 2.318.0
- @aws/dynamodb-data-mapper-annotations: 0.7.3

Comment: It looks like TypeScript is having trouble parsing the `unique symbol` type.  That type was added in TypeScript 2.7.  You must be using a TypeScript version older than 2.7 somewhere, even though you say you are using 2.8.1.  How are you building the project?  Just `tsc` at the command line?  If so, check `tsc --version`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt's comment. I resolves it by using newer version of `Typescript`.